# I have configured ssl on my teampass site on my test server. I dont see the "s" in the https://teampass.domain.org

Tags: ssl, https, ubuntu-14.04

When i try to visit  
I am able to access the site but I do not see the 'S" in the https://

I did my

1. apachectl configtest
2. apachectl stop
3. apachectl start
4. a2ensite default-ssl.conf
5. a2ensite teampass.conf
6. /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

I configured my virtualhost in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName teampass.domain.org
        Serveralias www.teampass.domain.org
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/teampass

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        SSLEngine on

        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/DigiCertCA
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/star_domain_org
        SSLCertificateKeyfile /etc/apache2/ssl/teampass.key
</VirtualHost>
```

this is my /etc/apache2/sites-available/teampass.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Redirect permanent / https://teampass.domain.org/
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName teampass.domain.org
    ServerAlias www.teampass.domain.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/teampass
    <Directory /var/www/html/teampass>
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/DigiCertCA
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/star_domain_org
    SSLCertificateKeyfile /etc/apache2/ssl/teampass.key
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName teampass
        ServerAlias www.teampass.domain.org
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/teampass

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/star_domain_org
        SSLCertificateKeyfile /etc/apache2/ssl/teampass.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/DigiCertCA
        SSLEngine on
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/teampass_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/teampass_access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                # DO NOT REMOVE
                RewriteOptions Inherit
        </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is my /etc/apache2/ports.conf

```
Listen 80
<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443 http
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        listen 443 http
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your port.conf change

```
Listen 80
<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443 http
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        listen 443 http
</IfModule>
```

by

```
Listen 80
<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Default 443 is already `https` if you set `http` right after, it will server `http` content on port 443

This is the configuration you need:

/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName teampass.domain.org
        Serveralias www.teampass.domain.org
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/teampass

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        SSLEngine on

        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/DigiCertCA
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/star_domain_org
        SSLCertificateKeyfile /etc/apache2/ssl/teampass.key
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/teampass.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Redirect permanent / https://teampass.domain.org/
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName teampass.domain.org
    ServerAlias www.teampass.domain.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/teampass
    <Directory /var/www/html/teampass>
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName teampass
        ServerAlias www.teampass.domain.org
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/teampass

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/star_domain_org
        SSLCertificateKeyfile /etc/apache2/ssl/teampass.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/DigiCertCA
        SSLEngine on
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/teampass_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/teampass_access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                # DO NOT REMOVE
                RewriteOptions Inherit
        </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, however it did not solve the problem. I made changes in the port.conf and also commented out <virtualHost *:80> from both default-ssl.conf and also teampass.conf. I made changes to the Certificate files as well but still serves with http.  @Froggiz

Comment: thank you @Forggiz for your consistant input. Redirect permanent / https://teampass.domain.org/ is in default-ssl.conf . currently IE says " This page can’t be displayed" . Chrome says "This webpage has a redirect loop

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" .. I am not able to view the page at this point.

Comment: is that for default-ssl.conf or teampass.conf ?

Comment: @Frogiz , I cant even explain lol. Alot of names i wanted to use was taken already i guess. lol

Comment: it did not work. should i put this same file from default-ssl.conf in teampass.conf ?  these are the files i have in sites available. the editing you did, i put it in default-ssl.conf.     root@teampass:/etc/apache2/sites-available# ls
\                 default-ssl.conf  teampass.conf
000-default.conf  index.html        teampass.conf.bak

Comment: currently IE cant find the page but Chrome can in http. @Froggiz

Comment: okay Chrome is trying to access it through https but page cant be found. I am now playing around with the permissions. @Froggiz

Comment: I added index.php to /var/www/html  and also in dir.conf in mods-available. and still  dont work. @Froggiz   and yes I will

Comment: so It finally worked. thank you soo much for your help. it was my fault , if you look at my document root. I had /var/www/html/teampass instead of /var/www/html .